# Does NSDictionary have a find-where type of functionality in objective c ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary

Say I have a list of records in my NSDictionary.  I know I can easily loop through the records to get all the values I want or add and if conditions to check for a specific value I want if I so please.

But here is my question, does the NSDictionary have a built in function call that allows you fetch a specific record in the set without looping it yourself?  Kind of like how you can perform a SELECT - WHERE X = "blah blah" in a database.

This is a curious question more than anything, if there is an easier way I didn't know about.

Comment: NSPredicate could be what you're looking for...

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  So you want to fetch a specific object in the dictionary if it matches your specifications?  So you want any and all objects that equal "blah blah"?

Comment: Larme, after doing some research on the use of NSPredicate based on your suggestion, this seems to be more the kind of functionality I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
NSSet * keysPassingTest = [dict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@"Blah Blah"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}];
```

This will give you a set of all the keys that correspond to a value equal to "blah blah"

Comment: Hey Logan, I think Lame's answer along the lines of the use of "predicate" is more what I was looking for